# BiBTeX reference API (from DOI)

Tags: api

Is there a robust API available to download BiBTeX references from a DOI?

E.g. a query such as  `https://api.somesite.net/10.1111/j.2517-6161.1995.tb02060.x` should return something like

```
@article{mackay1998choice,
    title={Choice of basis for Laplace approximation},
    author={MacKay, David JC},
    journal={Machine learning},
    volume={33},
    number={1},
    pages={77--86},
    year={1998},
    publisher={Springer}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know Python, [doi2bib](https://pypi.org/project/doi2bib/) might help you.

It seems that [CrossCite](https://citation.crosscite.org/) offers a similar service; take a look at the Documentation to see how it works.

Comment: I do know Python, thanks :). Although this package provides a commandline tool which is even better in my book! I will see how it goes.